# fgProcrustes is not aligning images properly for Morphometrics project using Momocs. Suggestions?

Tags: r, mathematical-morphology

I'm doing a project regarding leaf shape using Momocs in R to make the leaves similar enough to analyze them nicely. This is the first project my lab has done regarding this, so we're all figuring out how to use Momocs for this purpose. We developed a bunch of code and ran some tests on a small data set - they went well, so we progressed to full data analysis. But when I started processing the data in full, I ran into errors with the fgProcrustes command. Instead of aligning the shapes nicely, it fanned them out into a circle, even rotating some outlines 180 degrees!

This is what my initial tests looked like after using the fgProcrustes command.

[image]

This is what my current data sets look like after using the fgProcrustes command.

[image]

Here is the code I used, as well as the output of that code. I've tried using the other Procrustes commands, but they do not solve the problem. Otherwise, I've not tried very much - I've been learning R as I work through this project so I am unsure what to try.

```
test<-Out(coo)
stack(coo_center(test))
test2<-coo_smooth(test,100)
test3<-coo_center(test2)
test4<-coo_scale(test3)
test5<-coo_sample(test4, 500)

test6<-fgProcrustes(test5, options(verbose=FALSE))
stack(test6)
```

Here is the output of the code after running the fgProcrustes command.

> no landmarks defined in $ldk, so trying to work on $coo directly
>
> iteration: 1 gain: 48355000
>
> iteration: 2 gain: 8.7094
>
> iteration: 3 gain: 2.9068
>
> iteration: 4 gain: 0.061704
>
> iteration: 5 gain: 1.0681
>
> iteration: 6 gain: 1.4818
>
> iteration: 7 gain: 1.0683
>
> iteration: 8 gain: 0.22283
>
> iteration: 9 gain: 0.37984
>
> iteration: 10 gain: 0.50099

.....

> iteration: 86 gain: 3.638e-12
>
> iteration: 87 gain: 1.819e-12
>
> iteration: 88 gain: 9.0949e-13
>
> iteration: 89 gain: 1.819e-12
>
> iteration: 90 gain: 9.0949e-13
>
> iteration: 91 gain: 0

Any advise, suggestions, or ideas would be appreciated. Also any ideas on how to learn more about morphometrics in R would be welcome so that next time I have a problem I can solve it (without trial and error!).

Answer (score 0):

Your shapes possibly do not have the same rotation sense!
Feel free to contact me directly